# Designing for various resolutions under MDPI

Tags: android, android-layout

I am designing an application wherein I specify the dimensions for different DPI sizes in the dimens.xml. 
I am able to design for all the values except MDPI.
The problem with MDPI (landscape) is the different resolutions available like, 1280 X 800, 1024 X 600, 480 X 854, 480 X 800 and 320 X 480.
How do I design for all the above mentioned resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

Use Android asset-studio or draw9patch for MDPI design.

For refer link [Android asset-studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html#foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=33b5e5,0&crop=0&backgroundShape=bevel&backColor=ffffff,100),[Draw9patch](http://draw9patch.com/#url=http://draw9patch.com/image/btn.png&top%5B%5D=32&top%5B%5D=50&right%5B%5D=25&right%5B%5D=50&bottom%5B%5D=25&bottom%5B%5D=50&left%5B%5D=25&left%5B%5D=50)

Comment: Draw9patch and asset studio will help me with images for different values, but my problem is with the sizing of regular controls like buttons, textview, etc

Comment: @RatishPillai For regular control like textview,edittext you have to get the current screen.like android.view.Display display = ((android.view.WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); and apply width and height to your view.